# php fzaninotto Faker - How to Generate Only 5 Digit Zip Code?

Tags: php, zipcode, postal-code, faker

Is there a way to generate a 5 digit zip code/postcode using [fzaninotto's Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerprovideren_ustext)?

His provided function to do so, `$faker->postcode`, does not offer parameters to limit its size, so it often gives a 9-digit postcode instead of 5, e.g., 10278-4159 instead of 10278. This is problematic for seeding a database, because my sql database has a zipcode column of INT(5).

I know I can resort to just generating a random 5 digit number with Faker, but I wanted to know if there was a native way of generative 5 digit zip codes.

Comment: You could just shorten the returned zip code using [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) ->  `$postcode = (strlen($faker->postcode) > 5) ? substr($faker->postcode,0,5) : $faker->postcode;`

Comment: Zip codes shouldn't be integers. My city's zip code starts with a `0` so this would cause an issue. Demo of leading `0` issue; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/814ba/1... Couldn't you just take the first 5 characters?

Comment: "because my sql database has a zipcode column of INT(5)" Danger! Danger, Will Robinson! You're going to turn `02108` into `2108` and have to left-pad it for display. Zip codes are **not** integers.

Answer (score 7):

A workaround I found uses the postcode of the address class which always returns 5 digits.

Instead of `$faker->postcode` you can call `Address::postcode()`.

Don't forget to include `use Faker\Provider\Address;`.